# transformation matrices for linear transformation in different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm working on a problem for my linear algebra class and I can't seem to figure out how this works. The problem states:

Let  $$L: M_{22} \to M_{22} $$

where

$$ L(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}A $$

Consider the ordered bases

$$ S = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  \} $$

and

$$ T = \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}  \} $$

for $M_{22}$.

I'm supposed to find how to represent the linear transformation for the basis S, T, S and T, and T and S.

I guess I'm supposed to use transformation matrices in order to convert $L(A)$ to the other basis but I'm not quite sure how transformation matrices work for vectors in $M_{22}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: To find the matrix representation you apply the linear transformation and then write your outcome as a linear combination of the other basis and put the coordinates as your column vector